# How to fix 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position?

Tags: python

I have this code o python3 to print temperature value of hard disk

```
device = '/dev/%s' % self.device
tempRe = re.compile('%s:.*:(.*)' % device)
hddtemp = os.popen('/usr/sbin/hddtemp -q %s' % device)
    for line in hddtemp:
        temp = re.findall(tempRe, line)
            if temp:
                self['temp'].setText(_('Disk temperature: %s') % temp[0].lstrip())
hddtemp.close()
```

With some hard disk work just fine like this example I have got 34°C

```
/dev/sda: TOSHIBA MK2565GSX HR: 34°C
```

But with some information of some hard disk I have got as like this

```
/dev/sda: Thinklife SSD ST600 240G                ▒: 23°C
```

And the code given me this error

```
for line in hddtemp:
File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 51: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix it ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call popen with encoding

```
os.popen('/usr/sbin/hddtemp -q %s' % device, encoding='windows-1252')
```

I think your `setText` method is calling encode method of string class. string class default encoding is utf-8 and in utf-8 character 0x80 is not valid.